# AngularJs Changes don't show up

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem with AngularJs. I have a ready app and I would like to make some modification. First of all I just would like to log something out.
I modified the controller.js but when I upload to the server, it doesn't work. Actually if I delete the controller.js it still works.
So it doesn't matter what I do, it doesn't update on the server.

I deleted cache and also disabled it.

**I don't attach code, because I think it's not because the code. If I comment out a working part of the code, then upload it, it still works.

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a hard reload? In chrome with the development console open right click on the refresh button and select 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload'?

Comment: Yes, I tried it adn didn't help.

Comment: Are you using the same files? see sometimes we are changing other files instead of the originals

Comment: after you modify the code and before you upload to the server, did you try to test it on your computer? is there any error in the console?

Answer (score 0):

There is a task runner (grunt) who minifi and copy all JavaScript files in 1 file.
so you will need to run the task before.

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know. This app was made by a group of programmer and I just would like to make a little change. How can I get know If so? I am not really expert in AngularJs.

Comment: In the root of the project, there is a gulp.js or grunt.js file? or when you work in local you have to run gulp/grunt task in command prompt?

Comment: Yes, I found grunt on the server. But it is not really in the root folder.

Comment: when you show source (ctrl+u) in your web site, there is 1 javascript file with all of your code?

Comment: It is a webcam app and has more parts. It uses more javascript files like adapter.js, socketio.js and etc. But as I see there is a javascript file called app.min.js. I think that should be it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15632037)

Comment: ah yes it s that, so when you modifi your file, you have to launch your grunt task (with command prompt) to add and minifie your change and put   app.min.js on line

Comment: So there is an other file app.js which has angular.module(and the parts of the app). I think I have to grunt that file, right?

Comment: @kcsoft ok sry,i try to make the reputation for comment

Comment: i think app.js and app.min.js are generated by grunt, maybe someone who know well grunt could help?

Comment: Yea, I think I just have to run grunt somehow. But I don't really know anything about it.